# Windows Forms' CheckBox CheckedChanged vs. CheckStateChanged

Tags: .net, winforms, events, controls

Windows Forms' `CheckBox` control implements both `CheckedChanged` and `CheckStateChanged` events. As far as I can tell, both fire when the checked status of the checkbox is changed.

`CheckedChanged` precedes `CheckStateChanged`, but other than that I see no difference. Am I missing something? Should one be preferred over another?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My guess would be that it has to do with tri-state checkboxes.  This is the guts of the CheckState setter:

```
 if (this.checkState != value)
 {
   bool flag = this.Checked;
   this.checkState = value;
   if (base.IsHandleCreated)
   {
     base.SendMessage(0xf1, (int) this.checkState, 0);
   }
   if (flag != this.Checked)
   {
     this.OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
   }
   this.OnCheckStateChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
 }
```

Answer (score 82):

CheckState (and thus CheckStateChanged) allow for using a checkbox that can have three values: it can be checked, unchecked or 'indeterminate' - i.e. it has [ThreeState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.threestate.aspx) set to true.

If you're not using ThreeState, then CheckedChanged is all you need.

Comment: Its true! very simple, 2 step ( checked, unchecked ) use CheckedChanged, 3 step (checked, unchecked, indeterminate) use CheckStateChanged

Comment: What is `indeterminate` ??? The checkbox is either unchecked or checked, so what's the `indeterminate` thing?

Comment: See the link in the answer regarding the `ThreeState` property -  _"[ThreeState] gets or sets a value indicating whether the CheckBox will allow **three check states** rather than two."_ The third state is [CheckState.Indeterminate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkstate) - if i remember correctly, the checkbox gets filled in with a light gray colour when in that state.

Answer (score 15):

The two events are effectively the same unless you set the `ThreeState` property to `true`. Without having set `ThreeState`, both will fire when the check box is checked or unchecked and both will fire *after* the value has changed.

The main difference is when you do set `ThreeState` to true, which adds the `Indeterminate` `CheckState`:

- The control considers `Indeterminate` to be "checked". (`Checked == true`).
- Transitioning between `Checked` and `Unchecked` is the same as before.
- Transitioning between `Checked` and `Indeterminate` does *not* fire the `CheckedChanged` event, because `Checked` stays `true`.
- Transitioning between `Unchecked` and `Indeterminate` *does* fire the `CheckedChanged` event, because `Checked` changes from `false` to `true` or vice-versa.
- Clicking on a three state checkbox, the states transition from `Unchecked` to `Checked` to `Indeterminate` and back to `Unchecked`. You can still transition from `Unchecked` to `Indeterminate` programmatically.

(Note the difference between the `Checked` property, which is a two state boolean property, and the `Checked` state, which is one of the three possible values of the `CheckState` property.)

TL;DR: The main practical difference is that the `CheckedChanged` event doesn't fire on a three state checkbox when transitioning from `CheckState.Checked` to `CheckState.Indeterminate` or vice-versa, because both states are considered to be checked (`Checked == true`).

Answer (score 0):

Not an official answer to the question, but more of a follow-up comment.

I wanted to trigger 2 events when the CheckBox was clicked. In the Designer file, I could duplicate the line adding the event to the CheckedChanged, but as soon as I was modifying something in the Design screen, only the first event would be kept.

My solution was to add one event in CheckedChanged and the other to CheckStateChanged. Both events are now triggered when the CheckBox is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell:

`CheckChanged` is fired BEFORE the checked value is changed, so `.Checked` returns what the value WAS,

`CheckStateChanged` is fired AFTER the checked value is changed, so `.Checked`returns what the value IS

Comment: This is false, both events fire after the value has been changed.

Answer (score -3):

CheckState fires before the new value is committed.
CheckStateChanged fires after the new value is committed.

If your looking for dataset.haschanges to do an update after a checkbox value modification you need to use checkstatechanged event. Just make sure to disable threestate to keep from issues with NULL getting in there.

Comment: This is false, both events fire after the value has been changed.

Comment: @DaveCousineau I'm afraid TWood was correct. I had bound my checkbox's checked property to a public property in my form, with the binding set to update OnPropertyChange. When I tried using the CheckState event, the public property in the form had not yet updated. By the time the CheckStateChanged fired, however, the public property had been updated. Tangentially, the Click event fired after the two check-state events. For some reason, I thought it would fire first (from the general to the specific).

Comment: @RobertSF it's very easy to confirm. I suspect you and possibly this answer are referring to the WPF `CheckBox` which is not the same as the WinForms `CheckBox`. `OnPropertyChanged` is WPF as far as I know. But both of you refer to the non-existent `CheckState` event. There is no such event on either the WinForms or WPF `CheckBox` class or at least I can't find one.

Comment: @DaveCousineau My bad for the careless wording. I do mean WinForms, but the events are `CheckedChanged` and `CheckedStateChanged`. If you bind the checkbox's `Checked` property to a public property in your form (to allow external access without making the control itself public), setting the public property to update `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` you should observe that `CheckedChanged` fires first, then the public property updates, and then `CheckedStateChanged` fires. Maybe I shouldn't access public properties from within their own class. Then this wouldn't be an issue. :)

Comment: @RobertSF I'm not sure what "bind" here means but the point is that from both events, the value of the checkbox's properties have already been updated, such that if you read the value of the property from the event, it is the new value not the old value. this is not always the case with some events and can be tricky to work around (usually the new value would be in the eventargs instead). you are probably just seeing your events fire in the order that you hooked them up. I may try to confirm or disconfirm tomorrow.

Comment: @RobertSF reading the code, which Jacob G has also posted, it quite clearly sets the value and then raises the events. You say `CheckedChanged` fires first; well, the value was changed _before_ that event is raised, so all three of your events are occurring _after_ the value was changed. Your binding is probably working via the `CheckedChanged` event itself, and so it gets notified after your initial handler. But regardless of the order, none of these events are fired before the value is written.

Comment: @DaveCousineau By "bind," I mean where you have a public property `public bool trimFirst { set; get; } = false;` and you bind it to the checkbox's `Checked` property with `chkTrimFirst.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", this, "trimFirst", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));` If you intercept the `CheckedChanged` event, the checkbox's `Checked` property will be current, but the public property won't. The public property is updated sometime after the `CheckedChanged` event and sometime before the `CheckedStateEvent`.

Comment: @RobertSF I'm not sure how the binding mechanism works internally, but the binding fires immediately after the property changed event fires, whichever one it is you bind to. The `CheckedChanged` event is fired before the `CheckStateChanged` event, so if you bind to `Checked`, your binding is in between the two events, but if you bind to `CheckState`, your binding is after them. But either way this is decidedly NOT before the value of the checkbox has been updated. In all cases the value of the checkbox is updated first and then various events may fire in some order, including your binding.